# Python 3.1 twitter post with installed library,

Tags: json, twitter, python-3.x, urlencode

I'd like to be able to post twitter messages from python 3.0. None of the twitter API I have looked at support python 3.1. Since the post proceedure only requires this :

```
JSON: curl -u username:password -d status="your message here" http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json
```

I was wondering if it is possible with the standard libraries to format this so a message could be sent. My head says it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import base64

def encode_credentials(username, password):
    byte_creds = '{}:{}'.format(username, password).encode('utf-8')
    return base64.b64encode(byte_creds).decode('utf-8')

def tweet(username, password, message):
    encoded_msg = urllib.parse.urlencode({'status': message})
    credentials = encode_credentials(username, password)
    request = urllib.request.Request(
         'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json')
    request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials)
    urllib.request.urlopen(request, encoded_msg)
```

Then call `tweet('username', 'password', 'Hello twitter from Python3!')`.

The [`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) function prepares the message for the `HTTP POST` request.

The [`Request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) object uses HTTP authentication as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

The [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) methods sends the request to the twitter. When you pass it some data, it uses `POST`, otherwise `GET`.

This uses only parts of the Python3 standard library. However, if you want to work with HTTP, you should reconsider using third-party libraries. This [Dive Into Python 3 chapter](http://diveintopython3.org/http-web-services.html) explains how and why.

Comment: Works Like a charm, - point of note for anybody else trying it, if you send the same message twice it will throw an exception.